# case insensitivity on textbox not working

Tags: c#

I have a textbox used to make research by keywords in a datatable. When the table displays all the searched words are highlighted in yellow. The problem is that if I search `"hello"` and in the datatabase it is written `"Hello"` or `"HELLO"` the word won't be highlighted, I used `toLower()` but it's not changing anything, can someone give me ideas?

```
string word = tbSearch.Text.ToLower().Replace("'", " ");

e.Row.Cells[2].Text = ((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem).Row[2]
    .ToString()
    .ToLower()
    .Replace(tbSearch.Text, "<b class='highlighted'>" + tbSearch.Text + "</b>");
```

I tried that code it works if I make the research in minuscule, but if in the research I write `"HELLO"` it won't work. What I want is to recognize the keyword and highlight it regardless of case.

Comment: You might want to try and replace `tbSearch.Text` in the second line with the `word` you prepared. The way it is now it can't work if `tbSearch.Text` is not already in lower case.

Comment: Adding info to @ManfredRadlwimmer change the second line that contains `tbSearch.Text` to `word`

Comment: Im reasonably sure that case is not a problem in database queries. If i query my database for `namE` or `nAme` i still get the same results

Comment: @Takarii This has nothing to do with the database query.

Comment: @Fanto I think a better approach would be to keep the original casing for highlighting by doing a case-insensitive comparison. I'll post an answer for that shortly.

Comment: @Fanto It works, but you also lose all casing in the search results. If you don't care about the casing at all, that might be fine, but it also might be quite confusing to your users. My solution does a proper case insensitive replace instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current approach changes the casing of the input string. I'd recommend a different approach:

```
public static string Highlight(string text, string highlight, string prepend, string append)
{
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    int position = 0;
    int previousPosition = 0;

    while (position >= 0)
    {
        position = text.IndexOf(highlight, position, 
            StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);

        if (position >= 0)
        {
            result.Append(text.Substring(previousPosition, position - previousPosition));
            result.Append(prepend);
            result.Append(text.Substring(position, highlight.Length));
            result.Append(prepend);

            previousPosition = position + highlight.Length;
            position++;
        }
        else
        {
            result.Append(text.Substring(previousPosition));
        }
    }
    return result.ToString();
}
```

With this method, the result of

```
string x = "This test Test TEST should be highTESTjk lighted TeS";
string y = Highlight(x, "test", "<b>", "</b>");
```

would turn

> This test Test TEST should be highTESTjk lighted TeS

into

> This **test** **Test** **TEST** should be high**TEST**jk lighted TeS

instead of

> this **test** **test** **test** should be high**test**jk lighted tes

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `string.Replace` is case sensitive. So you'll need a way to replace that doesn't care about the case. Unfortunately, there's no way to make `string.Replace` case insensitive. Fortunately, we have regex:

```
var text = "This is my hello";
var searchText = "MY";

var result = 
  Regex.Replace
  (
    text, 
    Regex.Escape(searchText), 
    i => string.Format("<b class=\"highlighted\">{0}</b>", i.Value),
    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase
  );

Console.WriteLine(result); // This is <b class="highlighted">my</b> hello
```

Since you're probably going to use the same pattern many times over, you might want to keep a cached compiled instance of the regex, but that's up to you.